# Macro: Given row X copy specific cells from that row to a new sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a way to generate a list based on the value of each row in a given column (G). Currently the list can copy entire rows and works perfectly. It pulls all rows if column G contains the required text ("Card") and puts them in a list on another spreadsheet with no gaps.

The problem is that I want the list to only contain information from a few columns in each row containing "Card", not the whole row.

**Is there a way to make my code below pull specific cells from a row rather than using the .EntireRow function and copy the whole row?**

To clarify, this spreadsheet is updated regularly by multiple different users so the information is not static. Rows are added and changed frequently and occasionally deleted. As such I cannot just copy cell values from the original sheet to the new list.

```
Sub AlonsoApprovedList()

  Dim cell As Range

  Dim NewRange As Range

  Dim MyCount As Long

  Dim ExistCount As Long

  ExistCount = 0

  MyCount = 1

'----For every cell in row G on the ESI Project Data sheet----'

  For Each cell In Worksheets("ESI Project Data").Range("G6:G5000")

  If cell.Value = "Card" Then

      ExistCount = ExistCount + 1

      If MyCount = 1 Then Set NewRange = cell.Offset(0, -1)

      '----Sets up a new range to copy all data from the row if column G in that row contains the value in question----'

      Set NewRange = Application.Union(NewRange, cell.EntireRow)

      MyCount = MyCount + 1

  End If

  Next cell

  If ExistCount > 0 Then

      NewRange.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Alonso Approved List").Range("A3")

  End If

End Sub
```

**Additional information:**

1. Column G drop down data validation lists containing one several
   items. A complete list is in a different worksheet. Users go in to
   each line item and select from a specific category.
2. The other columns in question contain a line item's name, category
   (same as column G), a monetary value, and a date.
3. The code above loops through a list in the "ESI Project Data" Worksheet and detects rows by the value in cell G.  It currently copies the whole row every time a key word is in cell G ("Card") in this example.  I am using it to generate individual lists grouped by that key word.  I just want it to pull individual cells, not use the .EntireRow function as it currently does.  I do not know how to do that.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested...

```
Sub AlonsoApprovedList()

Dim cell As Range
Dim rngDest As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim arrColsToCopy

    arrColsToCopy = Array(1, 3, 4, 5)
    '----For every cell in row G on the ESI Project Data sheet----'
    Set rngDest = Worksheets("Alonso Approved List").Range("A3")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each cell In Worksheets("ESI Project Data").Range("G6:G5000").Cells

        If cell.Value = "Card" Then

            For i = LBound(arrColsToCopy) To UBound(arrColsToCopy)
                With cell.EntireRow
                    .Cells(arrColsToCopy(i)).Copy rngDest.Offset(0, i)
                End With
            Next i

            Set rngDest = rngDest.Offset(1, 0) 'next destination row

        End If

    Next cell

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked perfectly and I can't thank you enough!  I seriously appreciate your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

hello is there a code that I can use to copy specific cells to another workbook by clicking a button.

here's what I am trying to do,

from workbook 1 I need to copy info from the following cells
I have Column B info on cell A40 to A69
I have Column B info on cell b2, b3, b4, b8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15 and b40 to b69
I have column D info on cells b2, 
I have column G info on cell b1,b2,b3,b4

all this I need to send it to workbook2 which has the same cells assigned to this specific info.

hope I made my self clear.

Comment: If you want to ask a question, please use the `Ask Question` button, it's right there on the top